# Problems with using def function and saving variables

Tags: python, store, function

I want to make the following function to store **`all_tmp`** and **`all_date`** data and use them later. This is what I have...

```
def temperature(temp_file):
    '''
    This is a function that loads temperature data
    from WeatherUnderground. Type in the following:
    temperature('filename.filetype')
    '''

    file_obj=open(temp_file)

    all_dates=[]
    all_tmps=[]

    for line in file_obj:
        words=line.split(',')
        try:
            dates=parse(words[0])
            tmps=float(words[1])
            all_dates.append(dates)
            all_tmps.append(tmps)   
        except (ValueError,IndexError):
            pass

    file_obj.close()

    tempDat= return(all_dates,all_tmps) # This is supposed to store the variables...

(all_dates,all_tmps) = temperature(temp_file)
```

I want to open each of my functions in a separate script and plot them... But my variables (`all_dates` and `all_tmps`) won't store. Am I indenting wrong?

Comment: It's not clear to me what exactly you're asking about. Do you know how to `import` a module? That seems like the first place to start.

Comment: @Blckknght... I changed what I needed to do. My first obstacle is getting my variables to actually store. I don't know what syntax I need to store them. I've read other posts, but none have been that helpful.

Comment: what is the use of tempDat= return(all_dates,all_tmps) ? Are you getting invalid syntax message?.

Comment: I didn't get invalid syntax... it was one of my many desperate attempts to save the variables. I figured it was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

### Saving variables or just `return` 'em ?

The initially proposed concept of **`tempDat = return ( aTupleOfVALUEs )`**

fails
**`tempDat`** would have to already been declared in proper places as a **`global`** so as to allow to survive a `return` from inside of the code-scope horizon of **`def():`**-ed code and still remain "*visible*" / "*accessible*" `global`-ly ( <sub>which practice, while doable, is not always accepted as a good design</sub> )

It shall be fine for most of the cases to return values using simply

```
return aTupleOfVALUEs         # or any other representation of the results / data
```

### Tip to use a python context:

```
def temperature( temp_file ):
    '''
            This is a function that loads temperature data
            from WeatherUnderground. Type in the following:
            temperature( 'filename.filetype' )
    '''
    all_dates = []
    all_tmps  = []

    with open( temp_file, 'r' ) aFILE:
         for line in            aFILE:

             words = line.split(',')
             try:
                  dates = parse( words[0] )
                  tmps  = float( words[1] )

                  all_dates.append( dates )
                  all_tmps.append(  tmps  )

             except ( ValueError, IndexError ):
                  pass

    return ( all_dates, all_tmps )
```

---

<sub>For hawkish pythoneers, the post intentionally uses non-PEP-8 source code formatting as it is authors experience that during a learning phase, code read-ability improves the focus on task solution and helps getting used to the underlying concepts rather than to spend efforts on formally adhering typography. Hope the principle of providing help is respected and the non-PEP-8 styling format is forgiven in the name of the ease of reading.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global dictionary to save the values.

Something like this:

```
Saved_values = {}

def temperature(temp_file):

    <Code elided>

    Saved_values[temp_file] = (all_dates, all_tmps)
    return Saved_vales[temp_file] # replacing your return statement
```

Comment: I tried that but I still get an error that says Saved_values, all_dates, and all_tmps are not defined. Do I need to indent more than once? Or put those lines before I close the file?

Comment: Avoid tabs in your code. May be start with a simpler Hello world type of program.

Comment: Actually, I think I can't do what I want in the function script. If I put T= temperature('FileName.csv') in my second script, the date and temp values get saved.  Then I can just enter T[0] or T[1] to access the values and plot with them.

Answer (score -1):

first of all it should be `file_obj=open(temp_file, 'r')`
and then you need `file = file_obj=open.read()` to get the data out of the file. you only open it

> 'r' when the file will only be read, 'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be erased), and 'a' opens the file for appending; any data written to the file is automatically added to the end. 'r+' opens the file for both reading and writing. The mode argument is optional; 'r' will be assumed if it’s omitted.

from https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: You can iterate over an open file object to read the lines in it.

Comment: ahh right. I was in the wrong language. Sorry for this